# How would I go about preventing hotlinking of a PHP web service script that runs a query on a MySQL database and outputs it in JSON form?

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

**Introduction and background**

I have a MySQL database of Lottery Results which my Android application queries to get the results via a PHP web service script which connects to the database, does a query for the top 10 and returns JSON data for the Android client to parse and then display.

I have the server hosted and it uses Cpannel (cannot find the version number).

In terms of the Android app (java program) The full URLs of php script are stored in a String. I fear if the program got decompiled they could get access to this string. I am using pro-guard to obfuscate the code but this does not hide actual values given to Strings or variables.

**The actual Problem**

How would I prevent others (if they got the actual URL of the PHP script location) to prevent them from leaching the results I provide just by running the script (this would cost me bandwidth usage). I tested it and I could actually get the JSON data output if I input the full URL of the script.

**What I have done so far**

Im new to this server hosting and administration. So far I disabled indexing on the directory which contains the PHP scripts just in case someone found them that way.

I was looking into setting permissions for the script file but ended up actually blocking legitimate use of it. At the moment they are 644. I cannot remember which ones I tried.

I found various hotlinking tutorials but these seem to be for images and multimedia but not specifically a script which outputs JSON data. Please help me.

**What I am looking for**

I don't have any code to show but I am looking for advice for those who have been through the same problem and point me into a direction to which I can research, investigate and build a solution from.

Thank your for your time in reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick but not super secure solution would be to generate an unique token for every request:

Given:
Secret Key: examplekey1234

Client:
Calculates Token: sha256(examplekey + requestdata + date + ip ....)
Does request with token as additional request data

Server:
Calculates token the same way as the client.
Compares calculated with submitted token.
If both are equal, accept the request.

Since the secret key is known only to the client and the server, nobody ellse can calculate the token.
The data added to the calculation (requestdate, ip, date) ensures, that the token can't be reused for other requests (different reqest data, other user, at a later time, etc.).

If you have some kind of session id, you could also add it to your token calculation. This makes the token a little bit more secure, since it's only usable for this session.

But: When somebody decompiles your application, he can obtain the secret key. This method mainly protects against sniffing the network traffic to get the url.

Comment: I really like the idea thanks. I will try build a solution from this and let you know.